# Как с позиционировать блок в зависимости от положения скролла на React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Пишу проект на React, столкнулся с проблемой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скриншоте, блок выходит за границы родителя. Появляется этот блок при наведении на кнопку "Подробнее об условиях", как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на верхнюю кнопку "подробнее об условия" блок не достигал границ родителя и точно также для других кнопок и блоков ниже?

В данный момент у меня вот такой код:

```css
.rate-subitem-more__block {
    width: 426px;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(100% + 16px);
    padding: 28px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 12px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px 0px rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.26);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.rate-subitem__more {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    height: 43px;
    display: inline-flex;
    gap: 8px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: var(--main-button, #9d2235);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 0 17px 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    &:hover {
        & .rate-subitem-more__block {
            opacity: 1;
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
                <div className="rate-subitem__body">
                    <h4 className="rate-subitem__title">
                        {rate.title}
                    </h4>
                    <p className="rate-subitem__text">
                        {rate.text}
                    </p>
                    <div className="rate-subitem__more">
                        Подробнее об условиях
                        <div className="rate-subitem-more__block">
                            {rate.more.map((el, index) => {
                                return <div key={index}>
                                    <h5>{el.title}</h5>
                                    <ul>
                                        {el.ul.map((li, index) => {
                                            return <li key={index}>{li}</li>
                                        })}
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Есть решение в голове как это можно сделать, но больше похоже на костыль.
Грубо говоря нужен такой же функционал как на windows при клике правой кнопкой мыши по рабочему столу (Всплывающие окно будет позиционироваться от мыши в зависимости от места клика)

Comment: а он не из-за этого так располагается? top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); ? замените эти строчки на top: 0. Только у блока rate-subitem__more уберите position: relative и повесьте на rate-subitem__body . Тогда появляющийся блок будет у верхней границы блока тарифа.

Comment: Можно конечно так сделать, однако суть не в этом.
Я же могу проскролить ниже и ваше решение уже не будет работать т.к. теперь блок будет выходить за границы родителя внизу

Comment: попробовать для последнего rate-subitem использовать :last-child и у его rate-subitem-more__block уже top: auto, bottom: 0 . Так же можно убрать overflow:hidden у родителя чтобы не было обрезки. А так, если js, то хук useEffect и в нем нужный скрипт чтобы определять позиции конкретного итема относительно родителя и насколько всплывашка далеко от границ этого самого родителя, чтобы назначить ей top или bottom.

Comment: Касаемо last child не совсем верно, теперь если мы снова будет скролить вниз элемент выйдет за рамки. Убрать овервлоф не вариант.

А касаемо useEffect вполне правиль, но какую же все таки функцию написать, у меня сейчас вообще не получается к сожалению)